# Fazer upload via FTP de uma pasta inteira usando DOS

Tags: windows, upload, ftp, download, ms-dos

Eu preciso upar uma pasta (~300mb) que contém arquivos de um framework (magento) para o servidor em nuvem onde está a minha aplicação. A GUI do servidor só permite fazer o upload de arquivos individualmente e a criação de pastas tem que ser manual uma por uma. Para contornar esse imenso retrabalho, habilitei o FTP no servidor, baixei um software renomado e gratuito de gerenciamento de FTP, conectei ao servidor e comecei a upar os arquivos por lá. Deu certo em partes, acontece que a velocidade para upar é tão baixa que em 3 horas de upload foram transferidos 4MB, até que a conexão era interrompida por *time-out*.

Como outra alternativa, estou tentando upar via ftp do MSDOS, porém admito ser ignorante em DOS e não encontrei o comando certo, apenas comandos que copiam arquivos um a um manualmente. Teria que achar um comando que copiasse uma pasta e todo o seu conteúdo, alguém sabe qual é? Ou alguma outra forma para eu enviar esses arquivos?

Grato desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o comando **ftp** nativo do Windows só é possível enviar arquivos, se a pasta que quer enviar contém sub-pastas, essas pastas não serão enviadas.

Para copiar múltiplos arquivos de um único diretório basta utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
mput *
```

Se quer enviar uma pasta que contém subpastas recomendo utilizar o [NcFTP](https://www.ncftp.com), pode baixar o instalador para Windows neste [link](ftp://ftp.ncftp.com/ncftp/binaries/Setup%20NcFTP%203.2.6.msi).

Os comandos são bem parecidos com o ftp do Windows, para conectar utilize o seguinte comando:

```
ncftp -u seuUsuario -p suaSenha ftp.seusite.com.br
```

Para transferir arquivos e pastas, utilize o comando:

```
mput -r suaPasta
```